# rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23)

Tags: xcode14

I've xcode 14.2.I can't archive anymore for Any iOS Device (arm64) with the following error :
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/a0876c02-1788-11ed-b9c4-96898e02b808/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/main.c

Tries with $ pod deintegrate
$ pod cache clean --all